# Appending multiple parameters/arguments to a jsonp callback function

Tags: javascript, youtube, jsonp

How do I specify more arguments to be passed to a jsonp callback function?

For example, I'm trying to grab youtube video data:

```
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/gzDS-Kfd5XQ?v=2&alt=json-in-script&callback=youtubeFeedCallback
```

The javascript callback function that will be called is youtubeFeedCallback and it contains only one argument when called.

As of now the function would be something like this,

```
function youtubFeedCallback(response) {
...
}
```

What I would like to be able to do is pass a second argument like this,

```
function youtubeFeedCallback(response, divId) {
...
}
```

Is this possible to do. I've tried looking everywhere online and couldn't find anything.
Thanks!

Comment: The Youtube URL call is being done with an inline script tag. I'm making multiple video entry calls and need to pass a divId so I know which div element to use to put in the returned json video data. I would really like to pass in the divId at the time that the youtube URL is being called.

Answer (score 5):

You can't add arguments to the callback function like that. However, you can generate a wrapper function. The JSONP callback function just was to be a function in the default namespace, that means that you just need to add a generated function with a known name to the global `window` object. Step one is to make up a name:

```
var callback_name = 'youtubeFeedCallback_' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000);
```

In the real world you'd want to wrap that in a loop and check that `window[callback_name]` isn't already taken; you could use [`window.hasOwnProperty(callback_name)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) to check. Once you have a name, you can build a function:

```
window[callback_name] = function(response) {
    youtubeFeedCallback(response, divId);
};
```

You'd want to that up a little bit more though:

```
function jsonp_one_arg(real_callback, arg) {
    // Looping and name collision avoidance is left as an exercise
    // for the reader.
    var callback_name = 'jsonp_callback_' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000);
    window[callback_name] = function(response) {
        real_callback(response, arg);
        delete window[callback_name];  // Clean up after ourselves.
    };
    return callback_name;
}
```

Once you have something like that wired up, you could just call:

```
jsonp = jsonp_one_arg(youtubeFeedCallback, divId);
```

And then use the value of `jsonp` as the `callback` value in the YouTube URL.

You could build more functions like this to handle longer arguments lists too. Or you could build a general purpose one with [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/functions_and_function_scope/arguments) and [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply).

Comment: How would I be able to pass in the second argument at the time that the YouTube URL is called? I'm placing the YouTube URL as the src attribute of an inline script tag so it will execute as the page is loading and retrieve the necessary video data in jsonc format. I need the second argument to figure out which div element I will be placing that data in. Thanks!

Comment: @Jenn: Could you use an onload handler to set the `src` attributes? Start the page off with the `http://gdata.youtube.com/...` URLs in, say, `data-src` attributes, then your onload handler could transfer the `data-src` attributes to `src` attributes while calling `jsonp_one_arg` and patching up the `callback` parameter before setting `src`.

Comment: +1: but why using random instead of a simple counter creating say `"jsonp_1"`, `"jsonp_2"`, ... ?

Comment: @6502: Just so you don't have to keep track of which ones you've used. You could use a global counter if you wanted sequential ones, or you could loop through `window` looking for an open slot I suppose.

Comment: @6502: You could of course track the sequence number in a `jsonp_one_arg.sequence_number` property if you didn't want a global. But then you'd have to limit yourself to only `jsonp_one_arg` or go with the full blown general n-argument callback generator.

Answer (score 0):

better way is specify an associated array of divId and videoId like this

```
var arr = {
    'gzDS-Kfd5XQ': 'divId_1',
    'gwWS-Gasfdw': 'divId_2'
};
```

and in callback function get your divId by videoId

```
function youtubFeedCallback(data)
{
    var divId = arr[data.entry.media$group.yt$videoid.$t];
}
```

Comment: This would almost work except, If there was multiple array keys with the same videoid, I would get the correct divId. For example. If  var arr = { "gfefe-eee": 'divId_1', "gfefe-eee": 'divId_2' }; I have to worry about the  same video data appearing in separate div's. Thanks, though.

Answer (score 0):

When creating a "script" object, you can add attributes to it, and reference them later with document.currentScript.  This worked for me but other people may need something more elegant.

```
function blah(stuff,extraarg){
    cs=document.currentScript;
    console.log(stuff); // stuff is your json output
    console.log(cs.extraarg); // cs.extraarg is your extra arg
}

function thing(extraarg){
    var url='https://....&json_callback=blah';
    var s=document.createElement('script');
    s.src=url;
    s.extraarg=extraarg;
    document.body.appendChild(s);
}
```