# Pass parameters to Javascript callback functions

Tags: javascript, callback, parameter-passing

This is what I have:

```
function populateElement(arg1) {

    getData(arg1); 
}

function getData(query) {

    var url = "http://foo" + query + "&callback=processData";
    // do stuff 
}

function processData(results) {

    callbackForGetData(results); 
}

function callbackForGetData(result) { 

    // process data 
}
```

I want to pass two more arguments to function populateElement like so:

```
function populateElement(arg1, arg2, arg3) {

    getData(arg1);
}
```

And have the arg2, arg3 available in callbackForGetData

```
function callbackForGetData(result) {

    // process data
    // use arg2, arg3 here
}
```

How should I do this?

Comment: Why not call getData directly?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Appending multiple parameters/arguments to a jsonp callback function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6555172/appending-multiple-parameters-arguments-to-a-jsonp-callback-function). I offered an outline of a solution in an answer to this question.

Comment: @Adam: The problem is that `callbackForGetData` is being called as a JSONP callback so the OP doesn't have any control over how it is called.

Comment: mu is too short - First, this is not a repost. I'm new to JS and callbacks and I really don't understand what you mean by "doesn't have any control over how it is called". I can change the _callbackForGetData_.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass them on to the callback and access them in the `arguments` array

```
function getData(result) {
  //result === arg1
  //arguments[0] === arg1
  //arguments[1] === arg2
  //arguments[2] === arg3
  //and so on
}

getData(arg1, arg2, arg3);
```

Comment: His question is how you get arg1, arg2, and arg3 in his callback function.

Comment: I realize that, but i'm assuming that he doesn't want to, or can't change the callback, otherwise he could add parameters to getData and use them

Comment: This won't work. The problem is that the callback is getting called through JSONP. You need to [do something like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6555172/appending-multiple-parameters-arguments-to-a-jsonp-callback-function/6555275#6555275).

Comment: how did you find that out? It doesn't say it in the question... :|

Comment: @James I'm really confused with the callbacks. I can change the callback function. Could you give an example? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Pass an object as a single paramater:

```
function populateElement(arg1, arg2, arg3) {

    var params = {"arg1":arg1,"arg2":arg2,"arg3",arg3};
    getData(params);
}

function getData(params) {

    var query = params.arg1;
    var url = "http://foo" + query + "&callback=processData";
    // do stuff 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your are looking for a closure.

```
function getData(query) {
    var url = "http://foo" + query + "&callback=processData";
    // do stuff
    //simulate the callback
    processData("some results");
};

function populateElement(arg1, arg2, arg3) {
    //Because we define processData here, we have a closure scope that
    // lets us see all the arguments to populateElement
    window.processData = function(results) {
        console.log("ProcessData called with results: " + results +
            ", arg2: " + arg2 + ", arg3: " + arg3);  
    };
    getData(arg1);
}
//Simulate the starting call
populateElement(4, 5, 6);
```

[Here's a working jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/fvEKZ/)

Note this only supports a single (1) pending getData call.  A more elaborate scheme would be necessary to support multiple concurrent pending getData calls. Each would need a unique callback closure name, which could be as simple as a trailing numeric serial number.

Comment: I need to define a function nested within `populateElement` so I have access via closure to the `populateElement` arguments. I assign explicitly to `window` because being explicit like that is the clearest and least-confusing thing to do. Otherwise the JS default behaviors are well-known to be confusing, so best avoid ambiguity or unexpected/implicit behavior. Just my personal guideline.

Answer (score 0):

To pass more arguments, you can use `call` or `apply`.

```
function log(a, b, c) { console.log('A: ', a, ', b: ', b, ', c: ', c);}

log.call(window, 'first', 'second', 'third');
> A:  first , b:  second , c:  third

log.apply(window, ['first', 'second', 'third'])
> A:  first , b:  second , c:  third
```

But as Peter has suggested, you have some async stuff going on here and you want to save this on a closure, instead of passing extra arguments.

Have something like this, save your data in a closure:

```
function processData(results) {
  // transform data
  myModule.callbackForGetData(results); 
}

window.myModule = {

  populateElement: function(arg1, arg2, arg3) {

    this.data = arguments;
    this.getData(arg1); 
  },

  getData: function(query) {

    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = 'http://jsfiddle.net/echo/jsonp/?query=' + query + '&callback=processData';
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script)
  },

  callbackForGetData: function(result) { 

      // process data 
      console.log('Args: ', this.data, ', remote result: ', result);
  }
}

// test it
myModule.populateElement(1, 2, 3)
> Args:  [1, 2, 3] , remote result:  Object {query: "1"}
```