# AJAX JSONP call automatically adding callback parameter. How to remove that?

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsonp

I have few Services- with clean-URLs

and while calling each service, the URL  pattern is being checked.

Now am calling those URLs via AJAX from another server using JSONP technique.

But, while calling, its adding `callback` and `_(timestamp)` parameters with service-URLs, automatically.

The timestamp parameter is removed- by adding `cache : true` . But cant remove the callback parameter.

here is my AJAX calling code-

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url : "http://test.com/test/services/getFollowMeHistory/1/1/50",
        dataType:'jsonp',
        cache : true,
        crossDomain : true,
        //jsonpCallback : false,

        error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("Error occured while loading Loads."+textStatus);
            }
        });
});
```

Its calling the URL as- `http://test.com/test/services/getFollowMeHistory/1/1/50?callback=false` and am getting 404 from service side.

My service is returning data as **callbackMethod( {..JSON RESPONSE...} )**. So, it will automatically call the `function callbackMethod(data)` in my script. i dont need that callback parameter in my URL.

Just need to remove the `?callback=...` part from URL

Plz help.

Comment: It's JSONP, that's what JSONP is.

Comment: The callback parameter tells the server what callback to return with the data.

Comment: from service side- am returning json as- "callbackMethod({...json response..})". So it will automatically call "function callbackMethod(data)" in my script.

Comment: chech here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6555172/appending-multiple-parameters-arguments-to-a-jsonp-callback-function

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should set `jsonp: false` and not `jsonpCallback: false`. You should also explicitly set the `jsonpCallback` option to the callback name you expect to receive from the service.

Reference: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: I haven't tested it, just reading the docs, but apparently with `jsonp: false`, jQuery will not pass the `callback` parameter, but will still expect a JSONP response; that's why it requires the `jsonpCallback` parameter to explicitly state the name of the callback function to create, according to what is expected from the server.

Comment: Thanks but its a true cross-domain call

Comment: +1, this is definitely the way to go if you do not wish to use the callback parameter.

Comment: @AviC, this is correct. It will still be a jsonp call, since `dataType: "jsonp",` is there.

Answer (score 3):

1. If you set cacheing to `true` ie will cache the
   request response, and all subsequent JSONP calls will not return new
   data.
2. Without the callback JSONP is unusable, because there is no
   way to read the response. The callback is the whole point of JSONP.
3. Your server must be set up to handle a JSONP request. The url you send will not effect the client side. So your problem must be on the server-side. Which is where you should handle it. Making this not a jQuery problem.

If you are using a custom callback Try this, but a custom callback is not the same as removing the callback:

```
 jsonpCallback : "callbackMethod"
```

Comment: from service side- am returning json as- "callbackMethod({...json response..})". So it will automatically call "function callbackMethod(data)" in my script. I dont need that callback parameter.