# Firebase: Direct url .json not returning json

Tags: jquery, json, firebase-realtime-database

For some reason when I append `.json` to a firebase URL the result is not JSON.

Here is my structure in Firebase

```
MainApp
--user
---loggedIn : true
```

Now when I go to:

> https://appname-dcfce.firebaseio.com/user/loggedIn.json

in the browser it says 'true'

In the console preview I am getting:

> /**/ jQuery33104750711497605522_1519300615447(true);

This is the code I am using to query that:

```
$.ajax({
  url: jsonURL,
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  success: function(data){
    console.log( data );
  }, 
  error: function(data) {
    console.log("error");
  }
});
```

All I am getting in the console is:

> error

Any ideas?

Comment: Works for me: https://jsbin.com/zuhihol/edit?html,js,console. Can you check my jsbin and show what you've done differently.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen when I copy your JS exactly and put that into my code and run it, I still get error but I also get `Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery33105455794633642959_1519311087432 is not defined`. In the network it seems like it is adding: `loggedIn.json?callback=jQuery33105455794633642959_1519311087432&_=1519311087433`

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I used this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10955321/5675125 and it solved it :)