# Javascript $.getJSON callback and parameter passing

Tags: javascript, json, getjson

I currently have a $.getJSON call which is working fine as shown below.

```
var jsonUrl = "http://www.somesite.co.uk/jsonusv.php?callback=?";                   
$.getJSON(jsonUrl,function(zippy){
...some code
}
```

However, I wish to pass a variable with it so that the PHP script can use its $_GET[''] value and tailor the data.

I tired the fooling but could not get things to work any ideas ?

```
var jsonUrl = "http://www.somesite.co.uk/jsonusv.php?callback=?&value=65";
```

The php page looks something like this this had been stripped down. I did try to detect the $_GET['value'] but it didn't work.

```
<?PHP
header("content-type: application/json");  
$theSqlquery = "SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 20";   
$result131 = mysql_query($theSqlquery);

     if ($result131)
     {

        //make up Json string in $temp

    echo $_GET['callback'] . '(' . $temp . ');';
     }                 
?>
```

Comment: Hi Behnam Esmaili i don't understand your question

Comment: i have posted an answer.check.

Comment: Have you tried using a different name for "value" ... your jQuery/JS code works just fine. However, maybe there's a problem with using "value" as the name of a key (in PHP)?

Comment: possiblty this can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6555172/appending-multiple-parameters-arguments-to-a-jsonp-callback-function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var jsonUrl = "http://www.somesite.co.uk/jsonusv.php?callback=?";                   
$.getJSON(jsonUrl,{lastdatetime: "",},function(zippy){....
```

Seems to work ...

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest removing the `callback=?` from your jsonUrl

Comment: a url querystring starts with a `?` If you're checking the 'callback' property and want to pass an empty value just leave ?callback=&value=65".  I would imagine you're querystring is kind of jacked up with the question mark in the middle of it.

Answer (score 0):

Try passing your parameters into the `data` parameter of the function call instead of query string:

```
var jsonUrl = "http://www.somesite.co.uk/jsonusv.php";
$.getJSON(jsonUrl, {
    callback: "your callback val",
    value: "65",
  },
function(zippy){
...some code
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Then you can access them with `$_POST`

Note, `echo` sends the supposed json result back to your `$.getJSON()` method call, e.g., `success()` if it was successful. If you know the js method name in the `success()` method, and only need to pass it `$temp`, try this

```
var jsonUrl = "http://www.somesite.co.uk/jsonusv.php";
$.getJSON(jsonUrl, {
    value: "65"
  },
function(zippy){
    callbackMethod(zippy[0]);
});
```

and in your php

```
$output = array();
$output[0] = $temp;
echo json_encode($output);
```

Comment: but he wanna access it with  $_GET.

Comment: I am ok with POST but your method with no callback=? in the URL causes an Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Comment: Also its still GET not post.